# Update a custom LiveChat button text based state change

Tags: javascript, jquery, livechat

I created a custom LiveChat button. And I used the LiveChat API to open up the chat window from that button. I have a

tag inside the button that has some text that I would like to update based on if LiveChat is on or not.

Here is the code that I am using and how I tried to update the text on the button

```
LC_API.on_chat_state_changed = function(data) {
      alert("Chat state changed to: " + data.state);

    console.log(data.state);

      // if(data.state == data.state.offline){
      //     // set my button text here
      //     $("#robot-question p").text("Hello world!");
      // }
      // else{
      //     // set my button text here
      //      $("#robot-question p").text("Goodbye world!");
      // }
};
```

I'm trying to check the data.state to see what it's set to and then update the text accordingly.

I found the code example from here:[Live Chat API Docs](https://developers.livechatinc.com/docs/extending-ui/extending-chat-widget/javascript-api/#on-chat-state-changed)

Comment: `"Here is the code that I am using and how I tried to update the text on the button"` why doesn't this work? what's the actual problem you've encountered?

Comment: It doesn't change the text and I never get back my console log statement.